# Data being hidden when webscraping

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests, lxml

UPDATE: As DyZ commented below, my problem turned out to be that the source code did not have the necessary information.  So, I started using Selenium and it worked!!!

I am trying to web scrape and obtain the price of products from a website.  I am using the lxml and requests module.  So far what I have is:

```
import requests
from xml.etree import ElementTree as html


page = requests.get(myUrl)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
prices = tree.xpath('//div[@class="product-pricing"]/text()')
```

This should give me the list of prices but what I get instead when I print prices is:

```
['\n\t\t\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t', '\n\t\t\t\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t\t\t']
```

Does anyone know why this is happening/ how I could fix this?

Comment: Are you able to share the website? Pretty hard to help you without seeing the HTML.

Comment: Open the source code of the page in the browser. If the prices are not in the source code, you must use Selenium.

Comment: I edited and added the website.  The prices are not in the source code but it is shown in the developer tool window.  Does that still mean I have to use Selenium?

Comment: Please don't edit the question just to exclaim "UPDATE: Using Selenium worked!!!". Post an answer that explains what you did to solve the problem.